# Refreshing page - AJAX content away

Tags: ajax, cookies, refresh, reload

I have a navigation which load dynamically content via ajax. But if I refresh the page or visit another url and go back the current content is away and I see the old content under the first menu tab.

What is the best way to solve this problem? Can you give me some code?

The index.php include the elements navigation.inc.php and main_container.inc.php

```
<?php include("inc/incfiles/header_registrated.inc.php"); ?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION["userLogin"])) {
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/project\">";
}
else {
echo "";
}
?>
<?php include("inc/incfiles/navigation.inc.php"); ?>
<?php include("inc/incfiles/main_container.inc.php"); ?>
<?php include("inc/incfiles/footer.inc.php"); ?>
```

navigation.inc.php:

```
      <div class="navigation">

        <ul>
            <li id="1">
                <div id="menuImage1" class="menuImage"></div>
                <div class="menuText"><p>Punkt 1</p></div>

                <div class="navigationDart"></div>
            </li>
            <li id="2">
                <div id="menuImage2" class="menuImage"></div>
                <div class="menuText"><p>Punkt 2</p></div>
            </li>
            <li id="3">
                <div id="menuImage3" class="menuImage"></div>
                <div class="menuText"><p>Punkt 3</p></div>
            </li>
            <li id="4">
                <div id="menuImage4" class="menuImage"></div>
                <div class="menuText"><p>Punkt 4</p></div>
            </li>
            <li id="5">
                <div id="menuImage5" class="menuImage"></div>
                <div class="menuText"><p>Punkt 5</p></div>
            </li>
            <li id="6">
                <div id="menuImage6" class="menuImage"></div>
                <div class="menuText"><p>Punkt 6</p></div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

main_container.inc.php:

```
<div class="mainContainer">

        <div class="containerHeader">

            <div class="contentHeader">


            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="contentContainer">

            <div class="content">

            </div>

            <div class="advertisement">

            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
```

Now the divs content, cnotentHeader and advertisement (in file main_content.inc.php) is filled via ajax. Also the navigation has some jquery effects which also have to be the same after page refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get('inc/incfiles/content_container/header/1.php', function(data) {
    $('.contentHeader').html(data);
}); 

$.get('inc/incfiles/content_container/content/1.php', function(data) {
    $('.content').html(data);
}); 

$.get('inc/incfiles/content_container/advertisement/1.php', function(data) {
    $('.advertisement').html(data);
}); 
var current = '1.php';
$(".navigation li").click(function() {
    var quelle = $(this).attr('id') + ".php";

    // the current content doesn't load again
    if(current === quelle) {
        return;
    }

    current = quelle;

    // content
    $(".content").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).load("inc/incfiles/content_container/content/" + quelle).fadeIn('normal');
    })

    // advertisement
    $(".advertisement").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).load("inc/incfiles/content_container/advertisement/" + quelle).fadeIn('normal');
    })

    // header
    $(".contentHeader").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).load("inc/incfiles/content_container/header/" + quelle).fadeIn('normal');
    })

});

$(".navigation li").click(function() {
    $(".menuImage").removeClass("menuImageActive1");
    $(".menuImage").removeClass("menuImageActive2");
    $(".menuImage").removeClass("menuImageActive3");
    $(".menuImage").removeClass("menuImageActive4");
    $(".menuImage").removeClass("menuImageActive5");
    $(".menuImage").removeClass("menuImageActive6");
});

$("#1").mousedown(function() {
    $("#menuImage1").addClass("menuImageClick1"); // new class on mouse button press
});

$("#1").mouseup(function() {
    $("#menuImage1").removeClass("menuImageClick1");  //remove class after mouse button release
});

$("#1").click(function() {
    $("#menuImage1").addClass("menuImageActive1");
});



$("#2").mousedown(function() {
    $("#menuImage2").addClass("menuImageClick2"); // new class on mouse button press
});

$("#2").mouseup(function() {
    $("#menuImage2").removeClass("menuImageClick2");  //remove class after mouse button release
});

$("#2").click(function() {
    $("#menuImage2").addClass("menuImageActive2");
});



$("#3").mousedown(function() {
    $("#menuImage3").addClass("menuImageClick3"); // new class on mouse button press
});

$("#3").mouseup(function() {
    $("#menuImage3").removeClass("menuImageClick3");  //remove class after mouse button release
});

$("#3").click(function() {
    $("#menuImage3").addClass("menuImageActive3");
});



$("#4").mousedown(function() {
    $("#menuImage4").addClass("menuImageClick4"); // new class on mouse button press
});

$("#4").mouseup(function() {
    $("#menuImage4").removeClass("menuImageClick4");  //remove class after mouse button release
});

$("#4").click(function() {
    $("#menuImage4").addClass("menuImageActive4");
});



$("#5").mousedown(function() {
    $("#menuImage5").addClass("menuImageClick5"); // new class on mouse button press
});

$("#5").mouseup(function() {
    $("#menuImage5").removeClass("menuImageClick5");  //remove class after mouse button release
});

$("#5").click(function() {
    $("#menuImage5").addClass("menuImageActive5");
});



$("#6").mousedown(function() {
    $("#menuImage6").addClass("menuImageClick6"); // new class on mouse button press
});

$("#6").mouseup(function() {
    $("#menuImage6").removeClass("menuImageClick6");  //remove class after mouse button release
});

$("#6").click(function() {
    $("#menuImage6").addClass("menuImageActive6");
});




$("#1").click(function(){

    $(".navigationDart").animate({ 
        top: "16px"
            }, 500 );
    });
$("#2").click(function(){
    $(".navigationDart").animate({ 
        top: "88px"
            }, 500 );
    // Get the src of the image
    // var src = $(this).css("top");

    // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "img" in the POST data
    // $.post("/home.php", {"#2": top});
    });
$("#3").click(function(){
    $(".navigationDart").animate({ 
        top: "160px"
            }, 500 );
    });
$("#4").click(function(){
    $(".navigationDart").animate({ 
        top: "232px"
            }, 500 );
    });
$("#5").click(function(){
    $(".navigationDart").animate({ 
        top: "304px"
            }, 500 );
    });
$("#6").click(function(){
    $(".navigationDart").animate({ 
        top: "376px"
            }, 500 );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions. When you load content through ajax, store that response into a session variable and in your navigation you can add an if condition 
if(isset($_SESSION['ajaxresponse'])) etc.

Comment: Have you got an example, please?

Comment: Please reference your page where I can see the navigation, your question is not clear enough. I can write an example code for you if I have the big picture of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in your php file which serves your ajax request, please add the following line

```
// assuming that your contents can be stored in a variable $contents
$_SESSION['mycontent'] = $contents;
```

Now where you display your ajax response, add the following line of code there

```
if(isset($_SESSION['mycontent']) && !empty($_SESSION['mycontent']))
echo $_SESSION['mycontent'];
```

Make sure you are declaring session_start();

Hope this would be helpful! Sorry! If I could not understand the scenario of your problem.